# What does self(variable) do in Python?

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, self

I'm trying to understand someone else's code in Python and I stumbled across a line I don't quite understand and which I can't find on the internet:

```
x=self(k)
```

with k being a torch-array.
I know what self.something does but I haven't seen self(something) before.

Comment: This means that `self` is callable, indicating that this class may implement `__call__` magic method.

Comment: If `self` is within a `nn.Module`, then this calls the containing class's `forward` method (which is invoked from `__call__` as @MechanicPig points out).

Answer (score 3):

`self`, for these purposes, is just a variable like any other, and when we call a variable with parentheses, it invokes the `__call__` magic method. So

```
x = self(k)
```

is effectively a shortcut for

```
x = self.__call__(k)
```

---

Footnote: I say "effectively", because it's really more like

```
x = type(self).__call__(self, k)
```

due to the way magic methods work. This difference shouldn't matter unless you're doing funny things with singleton objects, though.